# How does eclipse distinguish SWT class from normal java class?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

A SWT class has Source/Design/Binding tabs, but normal one only has a Souce tab.A copy from a SWT class is treated as a normal class in eclipse, they looks the same in my eyes.
how to change a normal class to a SWT class in eclipse?

Comment: Did You pay attention to the includes/usings?

Comment: Which editor are you opening them in in both cases?

Comment: Eclipse remembers which editor was used to open a file and uses the same editor the next time you edit the file. You are probably using different editors for the files.

Comment: I've got it. Thanks both of you. The editor in Eclipse, I open the copy file with Windowbuilder Editor, bingo, that's what I want.

Comment: @Ron Please consider adding and accepting the solution you found for yourself as a proper answer since comments are not guaranteed to exist as long as the question itself.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu  I think  the  solution belongs to nitind & greg-449 and they should posted them as an  answer.